# Google Visualisation Line Chart, Logorithmic Display, values of 0 in data

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

When creating a Google Line chart I recently came across a problem and could not find the answer on Stack Overflow. After I recovered from my shock and found the answer elsewhere I thought I would post a Q&A here with the solution.

When your series contains data with 0s then if you are using a standard LineGraph everything looks fine:

[image: Line graph, standard scale]

(Note that I changed the numbers for this graph so you can actually see multiple lines without the logarithmic scale).

If you have a large scale disparity in your graph then one solution is to turn on logScale. however logScale just completely skips any values that are 0 or below, resulting in isolated lines on your graph:

[image: Line Graph, log scale]

The problem was how to have a Line Graph both display using a logarithmic scale and include 0 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is actually very simple, although I found a lot of people online recommending things like changing all the 0 values to 0.001, or even changing actual value to 0.001 and displayed value to 0.

There is a much simpler option though, it relies on an undocumented feature but it works perfectly in the current versions. Simply turn on scaleType:"mirrorLog" for the axis and now it will display 0 values as expected:

[image]

The final code for the example looks like this:

```
function drawVisualization() {

            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('date', 'Date');

                    data.addColumn('number', 'create');

                    data.addColumn('number', 'delete');

                    data.addColumn('number', 'modify');

                    data.addColumn('number', 'recycle');

                    data.addColumn('number', 'view');

            data.addRows([

                        [new Date(1386236040783),10477,8,28,2,2],

                        [new Date(1386322440783),13202,0,18,0,5],

                        [new Date(1386581640783),23856,0,105,0,6],

                        [new Date(1386668040783),9218,0,22,0,0],

                        [new Date(1386754440783),1441,0,14,0,0],

                        [new Date(1386840840783),832,2,7,0,0],

                        [new Date(1386927240783),240,22,41,4,4],

                        [new Date(1387186440783),2032,0,12,0,0],

                        [new Date(1387272840783),667,0,11,2,1],

                        [new Date(1387359240783),26535,50,69,11,16],

            ]);
            // Set chart options
            var options = {
                'title':'Activity over time',
                'animation.easing':'out',
                'animation.duration':1000,
                'pointSize':2,
                'vAxes': {0: {logScale: true, scaleType:"mirrorLog"}},
            };
            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
            chart.draw(data, options);  // Create and populate the data table.

 }
```

You can try it out at the Google playground, just copy the entire code into the method:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart

The important section is the configuration of vAxes to turn on `scaleType` to `mirrorLog`, there is no need to set `logScale` to true as well although it does no harm to do so.

Changing the options in `'vAxes': {0: {logScale: true, scaleType:"mirrorLog"}}` allows you to see the different behaviors. Just delete one or both of the configuration entries for the `vAxes` to see how the graph changes.

Comment: [Issue 984: Bug: Google LineChart...](https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=984) _However, there is an **undocumented feature** that might work for you.  You can set the 'scale' to 'mirrorLog', which supports 0 and negative values.  For negative values, it negates each value, computes the log of that, and puts the negative back on.  For values close to zero, positive and negative, it uses a linear scale._

Comment: Small correction:  You don't need both logScale and scaleType.  If scaleType is "mirrorLog" or "log", that will be enough.